# TemplateDoesNotExist django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know this question as been asked before but i have tried everything and still cant get it to work.

I have made a template file in /Users/username/Documents/python/skillshare/static/templates

This is my settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR ='/Users/chrismeek/Documents/python/skillshare/mvp_landing'


SECRET_KEY = 'w+u&5h%=iapf9cdj8d=9!!wppny54jc7a=_$ip2s6!!e!=w65^'

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'signups',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mvp_landing.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mvp_landing.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIR = (
    '/Users/chrismeek/Documents/python/skillshare/static/templates'
)
```

I then get this error

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Users/chrismeek/Documents/Python/skillshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/signup.html (File does not exist)
/Users/chrismeek/Documents/Python/skillshare/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/signup.html (File does not exist)
```

It works if i put the template files where its looking for them but wish to change them as it looks messy.

Comment: Have you considered using [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) to make these kind of setup issues less of a hassle? PS you should probably change your secret key now that you've posted it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is called [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs), not `TEMPLATE_DIR`. It should contain the list of locations where Django would search for templates:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/chrismeek/Documents/python/skillshare/static/templates',
)
```